# Given a set of locations and a single location, find the closest location from the set to the single

Tags: python, performance, ironpython

Given a set of locations and a single location, find the location from the set which is closest to the single location. It is not about finding a path trough nodes; it's about distance in a birds eye view.

The locations are a property of a 'node', (it's for a Finite Element software extension). Problem is: this takes to friggin long. I'm looking for something quicker. One user has to call this function up to 500 times (with a different single location) on a set of 1 million locations (the set stays the same).

I'd rather not limit the set before doing this calculation; I don't have to query a database or anything; I feel this simple arithmethics should be done in a few ms anyway. I don't get why it takes so long.

```
# excerpt of how LocationByNodeId looks like. 40k keys is a small model, can contain up to a million keys.
node_location_by_nodeId = {43815: (3.2835714285714266, -1.8875000000000068, 0.23571428571420952), 43816: (3.227857142857142, -1.8875000000000068, 0.23571428571421035)}
location_in_space=(1,3,7)

def node_closest_to_location_in_space(location_in_space):
    global node_location_by_nodeId
    distances = {}
    for NodeId in node_location_by_nodeId:
        NodeLocation = node_location_by_nodeId[NodeId]
        distances[NodeId] = (NodeLocation[0] - location_in_space[0])**2 + 
                            (NodeLocation[1] - location_in_space[1])**2 + 
                            (NodeLocation[2] - location_in_space[2])**2
    return min(distances, key=distances.get) # I don't really get this statement, i got it from here. Maybe this one is slow?

node_closest_to_location_in_space(location_in_space)
```

edit: solution taken from answers below reduced runtime to 35% of original runtime in big data set (400 calls over a set of 1.2million).

```
closest_node = None
closest_distance = 1e100  # An arbitrary, HUGE, value
x,y,z = location_in_space[:3]
for NodeId, NodeLocation in LocationByNodeId.iteritems():
    distance = (NodeLocation[0] - x)**2 + (NodeLocation[1] - y)**2 + (NodeLocation[2] - z)**2
    if distance < closest_distance:
        closest_distance = distance
        closest_node = NodeId
return closest_node
```

Comment: You would benefit from [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: You should look at [R-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing into your location argument takes time, and location doesn't change for all your million nodes, so lift these invariants out of the for loop:

```
for NodeId, NodeLocation in node_location_by_nodeId.iteritems():
    distance = (NodeLocation[0] - location_in_space[0])**2 + 
               (NodeLocation[1] - location_in_space[1])**2 + 
               (NodeLocation[2] - location_in_space[2])**2
    if distance <= closest_distance:
        closest_distance = distance
        closest_node = NodeId
```

becomes:

```
x,y,z = location_in_space
for NodeId, NodeLocation in node_location_by_nodeId.iteritems():
    distance = (NodeLocation[0] - x)**2 + 
               (NodeLocation[1] - y)**2 + 
               (NodeLocation[2] - z)**2
    if distance <= closest_distance:
        closest_distance = distance
        closest_node = NodeId
```

Now these become simple (and faster) local value references.

You can also try replacing your distance calculation with calls to `math.hypot`, which is implemented in fast C code:

```
from math import hypot

x,y,z = location_in_space
for NodeId, NodeLocation in node_location_by_nodeId.iteritems():
    distance = hypot(hypot((NodeLocation[0] - x), (NodeLocation[1] - y)),(NodeLocation[2] - z))
    if distance <= closest_distance:
        closest_distance = distance
        closest_node = NodeId
```

(`hypot` is written to only do 2D distance calculation, so to do 3D you have to call `hypot(hypot(xdist,ydist),zdist)`.)

Comment: Droppin the distances as a dictionary brought me from 21 to 14 minutes. Moving the location_in_space saved another 6, bringing me to 7. Hypot, however, costs me an additional 4. Appearantly hypot(hypot(x,y),z) is not faster than x**2+y**2+z**2

Comment: Ah! hypot returns the SQRT(x**2,y**2). I omited the sqrt for performence already; i'm not interested in the actual distance, i only want to know who is closest. So the hypot variant adds some EXTRA calculations!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a simple linear search on an unsorted dict and expect it to be fast (at least not very fast). 
There are so many algorithms that helps you tackle this problem in a much optimized way.

An [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) as suggested is the perfect data structure to store your locations.

You can also look for solutions in this wikipedia page: [Nearest Neighbor Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating, and destroying, a dictionary (`distances`) with a million items each time you run this function, but that's not even necessary. Try this:

```
def node_closest_to_location_in_space(location_in_space)
    global node_location_by_nodeId
    closest_node = None
    closest_distance = 1e100  # An arbitrary, HUGE, value
    for NodeId, NodeLocation in node_location_by_nodeId.iteritems():
        distance = (NodeLocation[0] - location_in_space[0])**2 + 
                   (NodeLocation[1] - location_in_space[1])**2 + 
                   (NodeLocation[2] - location_in_space[2])**2
        if distance <= closest_distance:
            closest_distance = distance
            closest_node = NodeId
    return (closest_node, closest_distance)
```

I believe the overhead involved in creating and tearing down that `distances` dict every time you call the function was what was killing your performance. If so, this version should be faster.

Comment: Note that if you're using Python 3, `iteritems()` has been renamed to `items()`. If you're using Python 2, it's important to use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`, because `items()` will build a list of all the items before returning. With a million entries in your location dict, that's a lot of overhead; an iterator (which can be built and returned in constant time) is much better.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use `global node_location_by_nodeId`. You should use `global` when you want to *assign* a value to a global variable. Also, instead of doing `closest_distance = 1e100`, which may produce wrong results with big distances, you can use `closest_distance = float('+inf')`.

Comment: (The Python 3 version of `items()` is an iterator, and the list version has been removed).

Comment: Bakuriu - good point. I just copied the OP's code, and was focused on getting rid of that million-item dict.

To the OP: you can also delete the `global node_location_by_nodeId` line; it serves no purpose in your code as it stands, since you're not modifying that dict in any way.

Comment: Thanks, this one saves already ~20% in my small sandbox and I actually understand this one.